# Unix command to print the 2nd part of the data after matched pattern

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a specified set of string with some keywords to match.

Key words are : string will contain "CREATESETTABLE" and dot(.) and TABLENAME
In below sample string, DATABASE1 and DATABASE2 are dynamic but after that a dot(.) will come then followed by TABLENAME; but dot(.) and TABLENAME may repeat n times.

> string="CREATESETTABLEDATABASE1.TABLE1(uid)CREATESETTABLEDATABASE1.TABLENAMEuid,cid,mid)DATABASE2.TABLENAME(hi,hello)"

What i used is :

```
echo "$string" | awk -F'CREATESETTABLE+[^ ]+.TABLENAME' '{print $2}'
```

Actual out put is : `(hi,hello)`

Expected out put is: `uid,cid,mid)DATABASE.TABLENAME(hi,hello)`

**Note:** Use the keywords which i specified in this example. Dont use other keywords such as "(" ; other data are dynamic only what i said is static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `sed`,

```
echo $string | sed 's/.*CREATESETTABLE[^)]\+TABLENAME\(.*\)/\1/g'
```

As mentioned in comments,

```
sed -e 's/.*CREATESETTABLE[^)]\+TABLENAME\(.*\)/\1/g' -e 's/.*CREATEMULTISETTABLE[^)]\+TABLENAME\(.*\)/\1/g'
```

Comment: table name should be used in key word because i may have n number of different tables. its not that i always match first tablename. i may have match in second table name

Comment: good. Please explain it in the answer as well. i could not understand `\1/g`

Comment: Do not use "(" as i described in the question Note. Because it may or may not come

Comment: @logan, I haven't used `(` in my regex. It is a grouping/capturing in `sed`. The captured string is back referenced by `\1`.

Comment: +1 for you. Could you also please let me know if can use OR condition in sed search. say `sed 's/.*CREATEMULTISETTABLE[^)]\+TABLENAME\(.*\)/\1/g` and `sed 's/.*CREATESETTABLE[^)]\+TABLENAME\(.*\)/\1/g` both should operate as single command  ?

Comment: your answers are ultimate :)

Comment: @logan, `-e` is used to add another `sed` expression. Or, you can even use like this : `sed -e 's/.*CREATESETTABLE[^)]\+TABLENAME\(.*\)/\1/g; s/.*CREATEMULTISETTABLE[^)]\+TABLENAME\(.*\)/\1/g'`. Note the `;` to separate two expression.